# Why am I getting a compile error on the ToList() and how do you separate each sql column into a sparate list element?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

```
 String priceID = codeArray[0];

        var priceResult = from PRICE_LIST in priceContext.PRICE_LIST
                      where PRICE_LIST.PRICE_ID == priceID
                      select new
                      {
                       PRICE_LIST.RETAIL,
                       PRICE_LIST.WHOLESALE
                      }.ToList();
```

I'm receiving a compile error that the anonymous type does not contain a definition for ToList() and I'm not sure why? I've seen many examples where queries are stored using this method. I can do priceResult.ToList(), but both the retail and wholesale price columns are in the same list element. So I can't get retail by selecting the first element ect. New to EF & LINQ and still on the learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the entire LINQ within parentheses like this:

```
var priceResult = (from PRICE_LIST in priceContext.PRICE_LIST
                      where PRICE_LIST.PRICE_ID == priceID
                      select new
                      {
                       PRICE_LIST.RETAIL,
                       PRICE_LIST.WHOLESALE
                      }).ToList();
```

otherwise it tries to make each new object to a list

Comment: Great! That worked. Now how do you deal with the resulting list that has both prices in the same element[0] of the list? I need to create two separate variable from the two sql columns.